# Form with AJAX callback to query database and display info in block['content']

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a simple select form that I want to use as a "Sort By" handler. When user chooses a different option I want it to change the query and display the new results. E.G. sort by duration ASC or sort by duration DESC.

This is my form:

```
function mortgage_multi_view_sort_form($form, &$form_state) {
     $form = array();
     $sortOptions = array(
        1 => t('Mortgage Duration: Shortest to Longest'),
        2 => t('Mortgage Duration: Longest to Shortest'),
     );

     $form['mortgage_sort'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Sort By'),
        '#options' => $sortOptions,
        '#default_value' => 1,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#ajax' => array(
            'event' => 'change',
            'callback' => 'ajax_select_callback',
            //'wrapper' => 'replace_model_div',
            'method' => 'replace',
            //'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
     );

     return $form;
 }
```

When they change this to Longest to Shortest I want to asynchronously display the mortgages in reverse order. Is this best to do in the callback function?

My callback function (currently):

```
 function ajax_select_callback($form, &$form_state){
 switch($form['mortgage_sort']){
    case 1:
        $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {mortgage_database} ORDERBY duration DESC');
        displayMortgages($result);
        break;
    case 2:
        $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {mortgage_database} ORDERBY duration ASC');
        displayMortgages($result);
        break;
 }
```

}

In my displayMortgages() function it just takes the entire query and displays it in a table. How do I get this information to block['content'] from my displayMortgages() now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do all the logic in the form function. However with your particular issue, I would approach it slightly differently. I would simply return the table HTML from `displayMortgages()` back to the form and display the table as part of the form. But just simply as a `#type=> 'markup'`. That way, your sort form and the results are one, and you don't need to worry about firing off another ajax command somewhere else.

So your form code would basically be:

```
function mortgage_multi_view_sort_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  // Default sort direction
  $sort_dir = 'DESC';

  $sortOptions = array(
    'DESC' => t('Mortgage Duration: Shortest to Longest'),
    'ASC' => t('Mortgage Duration: Longest to Shortest'),
  );

  $form['mortgage_sort'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Sort By'),
    '#options' => $sortOptions,
    '#default_value' => 'DESC',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'change',
      'callback' => 'ajax_select_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'replace_model_div',
      'method' => 'replace',
      //'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );

  // Check if a selection on the form has been made, if so then update the direction
  if (isset($form_state['values']['mortgage_sort'])) {
    $sort_dir = $form_state['values']['mortgage_sort'];
  }

  $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {mortgage_database} ORDERBY duration '.$sort_dir);

  $form['result'] = array(
    '#markup' => (count($result)) ? displayMortgages($result) : '',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_model_div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

And you just need to return the part that's being replaced in your ajax callback:

```
function ajax_select_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  // Just a return of result is sufficient since it's being replaced
  return $form['result'];
}
```

Comment: Oh my god that makes so much more sense. I was soooo close to an answer. I was hellbent on making the "table" it's own block and printing it but just using it all in the sort_form block and using AJAX to div replace works the same exact way but is cleaner/quicker.

Say I was adding more select options like sorting by "amount" or something, would you recommend a switch/case in the hook_form and have my differing queries listed in there?

Comment: @Exziled Yes, you can perform the query in your form builder, but I would just add a new variable `$sort_field` and implement the same logic as `$sort_dir` and you can replace `ORDERBY duration` with `ORDERBY '.$sort_field.'`

Comment: @Exziled there is a way to do it without having it all in the form though using [Ajax Commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7), particularly the `ajax_command_replace`. Read how to use commands [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7)

Comment: I'll take a look at the `ajax_command_replace` and see what I can figure out! I definitely want to aim to do this best practice to eliminate fixes later. It's great practice :D

Comment: one last question! If I have another AJAX form on my page such as "filter mortgages" could I essentially use the same callback and `$form['result']` with the #markup for it? It'll still replace the same content? I figured it's worth a shot at asking before I spend a few hours doing it xD

Comment: I suppose you could, given that it's only HTML. But why would you separate your filters into 2 forms? That's just bad design.

Comment: one will be a "filter" that actually only displays mortgages that meet the criteria vs. what I had been doing which just sorts them ALL in that specified order. 

I want to dynamically adjust the Result Set based on the filters but I want the sort to display them in ASC/DESC order. 

IE: they only want to see mortgages with an 'A' grade and then want to sort them by how much the property costs!

Comment: It could be done using jQuery .hide() or something but figured if I already ahve the code written out I might as well use it!